# Matching Current Excel User Profile to a List of Cells

Tags: excel, list

I am trying to match the current user on an Excel profile to a list of names on a particular worksheet. Given that it is a particular user upon running the function His/Her photo should get inserted into a specific cell. I have already done the following:

```
Sub Input_by()

Dim myPassword As String
Dim fPath As String
Dim tDate As String
myPassword = "trade2013"
Sheets("Collection Slip").Unprotect Password:=myPassword

If Environ$("UserName") = "LeonQi" Then
    Sheets("Collection Slip").Select
    Range("B29").Select
    With Sheets("Collection Slip").Pictures.Insert _
        ("G:\ITS\Shared\Signature\Leon Qiao.jpg")
         .Top = Range("B31").Top
         .Left = Range("B31").Left
         .Width = 250
         .Height = 58
    End With
    Sheets("Collection Cover Sheet").Select
    Range("G31").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Environ$("UserName")
    Sheets("Collection Slip").Select
    Range("B29").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Leon Qiao"
    Sheets("Collection Cover Sheet").Select

ElseIf Environ$("UserName") = "RoisinK" Then
    Sheets("Collection Slip").Select
    Range("B29").Select
    With Sheets("Collection Slip").Pictures.Insert _
        ("G:\ITS\Shared\Signature\Roisin Kehoe.jpg")
        .Top = Range("B31").Top
        .Left = Range("B31").Left
        .Width = 250
        .Height = 58
    End With
    Sheets("Collection Cover Sheet").Select
    Range("G31").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Environ$("UserName")
    Sheets("Collection Slip").Select
    Range("B29").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Roisin Kehoe"
    Sheets("Collection Cover Sheet").Select

ElseIf Environ$("UserName") = "LiamT" Then
    Sheets("Collection Slip").Select
    Range("B29").Select
    With Sheets("Collection Slip").Pictures.Insert _
        ("G:\ITS\Shared\Signature\Liam Tressler.jpg")
        .Top = Range("B31").Top
        .Left = Range("B31").Left
        .Width = 250
        .Height = 58
    End With
    Sheets("Collection Cover Sheet").Select
    Range("G31").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Environ$("UserName")
    Sheets("Collection Slip").Select
    Range("B29").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Liam Tressler"
    Sheets("Collection Cover Sheet").Select

End If

Sheets("Collection Slip").Protect Password:=myPassword

End Sub
```

However What I have realised is that its not very user friendly in that, a non VBA capable person would not know how to update the list through coding.  Thus I am just wondering if there is anyway which I can get a code that runs through all the existing list of names (On Column A in sheet called "User Management") and match it against the current Excel User. If the current User is = founded on the list then insert his/her picture, else we exist the Sub.

Thanks for your help

Leon

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do, the following might work for you. Say the list of user names you want to check is in the range A1:A100 in sheet "User Management". And let's say also that in the same sheet, in cells B1:B100, is a list of the full names that are used in naming the `jpg` picture files.

```
Sub AddPix()

    Dim userNames() As String
    Dim userPixNames() As String
    Dim currentUser AS String

    With Worksheets("User Management")       
        'Assign the user names to an array (much faster than looping through range)
        userNames = .Range("A1:A100")
        userPixNames = .Range("B1:B100")
    End With
    For i = 1 To 100
        'The 1 in userNames(i,1) is needed because of the way
            'VBA creates an array assigned directly from a range
            '(as we did above)
        If Environ$("UserName") = userNames(i, 1) Then
            'Have I missed where the picture will be inserted?
            With Sheets("Collection Slip").Pictures.Insert _
                ("G:\ITS\Shared\Signature\" & userPixNames(i, 1) & ".jpg")
                .Top = Range("B31").Top
                .Left = Range("B31").Left
                .Width = 250   
                .Height = 58
            End With
            'short-circuit the For loop when current user's name is found               
            i = 100
        End If
     Next i
End Sub
```

On a side note, you can avoid most, if not all, of the Selects in your code (which is good because Selects are slow). For example,

```
Sheets("Collection Cover Sheet").Select
Range("G31").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Environ$("UserName")
```

would more usually be written as something like

```
Dim wsCover as Worksheet
Set wsCover as Worksheets("Collection Cover Sheet") 

wsCover.Range("G31").Value = Environ$("UserName")
```

The assignment of the worksheet to a worksheet object with a shorter name is just to make the code easier to read. No performance hit, either.

Comment: Thanks Chuff. I am getting an error of Type Mismatch on the userNames= .Range("A1:A100") Part. Can you help me out?